# MT.exe changing "language" by "culture" in the generated assembly

Tags: visual-studio-2010, manifest, winsxs

I'm trying to install in WinSxS a MUI version of my dll.

I'm creating a manifest file for the localized dll with mt.exe with the next assembly identity:

```
Digi21.mui,type=win32,language=es,version=10.0.0.198, processorArchitecture=x86,publicKeyToken=82292917b7a6e156
```

The generated manifest file is this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<assembly xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1" manifestVersion="1.0">
  <assemblyIdentity culture="es" name="Digi21.mui" processorArchitecture="x86" publicKeyToken="82292917b7a6e156" type="win32" version="10.0.0.198"></assemblyIdentity>
</assembly>
```

When trying to load the Dll, the Activation Context can't be created because of the "culture" attribute.

If I change the name of the attribute to "language" it's working well.

Why is mt.exe creating a "culture" attribute and not a "language" attribute?

How can I forze mt.exe to create the "language" attribute and not the "culture" one?

Thank you.

Comment: A MUI file should not contain any code, just resources.  Which are culture dependent, you wouldn't use the same strings for, say, es-ES vs es-MX.  The heavily re-engineered MUI support in Vista probably has something to do with mt.exe substituting the attribute.  Hard to tell, manifests are not well documented.

Comment: This file has only resources and it loads correctly when I sustitute the Word "culture" with "language". 

I want to know if this is an error in MT.EXE, because "culture" is not valid in the "assemblyIdentity" element.

Comment: I doubt it.  I suspect you'll have to call Microsoft Support to get a "yeah, it's a bug" answer.  That's an expensive answer and still doesn't solve your problem.  SO users are more typically interested in finding out what it takes to get their problem solved.  You'll have to fix your manifest to get ahead.  The way Windows automatically locates the mui file is documented well enough [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa374224%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).